# cmake detect which library libc++ or libstdc++ is configured to be used against g++ or clang++

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang, libstdc++, libc++

I wrote an `CMakeLists.txt` to build a project with either `g++` or `clang++`.

To catch as many as possible bugs I use both `libc++` with `-D_LIBCPP_DEBUG2=2` (for `clang++`) and `libstdc++` with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (for both `g++` and `clang++`).

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-ggdb -fno-inline -DDEBUG=1 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic")
#[[
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D_LIBCPP_DEBUG2=2")
elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "GNU")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG")
endif()
]]
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -DNDEBUG=1 -march=native")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "RelWithDebInfo")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-fno-omit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG=1 -march=native")
    if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -O3 -gline-tables-only")
    elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "GNU")
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -Og -ggdb")
    endif()
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "-Os -DNDEBUG=1 -march=native")
else()
    message(STATUS "Wrong build type selected, defaulted to Debug.")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
endif()
```

Commented out code is the point where I should to know which library currently will be used with current compiler.

How to achieve this? I know, that `libstdc++` defines `__GLIBCXX__` and `libc++` defines `_LIBCPP_VERSION`, but how to detect them?

Comment: Surely I can pass both flags to `clang` debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assistance of CMake's [CheckCXXSymbolExists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXSymbolExists.html) module, you can determine whether libc++ or libstdc++ is configured to be used in your project. Here's how you can do it:

```
include(CheckCXXSymbolExists)

if(cxx_std_20 IN_LIST CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES)
  set(header version)
else()
  set(header ciso646)
endif()

check_cxx_symbol_exists(_LIBCPP_VERSION ${header} LIBCPP)
if(LIBCPP)
  # Logic for libc++
endif()

check_cxx_symbol_exists(__GLIBCXX__ ${header} GLIBCXX)
if(GLIBCXX)
  # Logic for libstdc++
endif()
```

In this implementation, we use the [<version>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version) header if the compiler supports C++20. Otherwise, we resort to the [<ciso646>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646) header. Note that while `<ciso646>` is removed in C++20, it may still exist in implementations for backward compatibility purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can safely just pass both defines for each library.

But if you really want to do this conditionally, I'd recommend using [CheckCXXSourceCompiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXSourceCompiles.html) module with following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int a =
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    1;
#else
    fgsfds;
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
return 0;
}
```

If that code compiles, then you are using libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

In source code you may:

```
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

#if defined(__cplusplus) && defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION)
// This indicates that libc++ is being used
#   pragma message("libc++ version: " STR(_LIBCPP_VERSION))
#endif

#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
// This indicates that libstdc++ is being used
#   pragma message("libstdc++ version: " STR(__GLIBCXX__))
#endif
```

When you build you should see:

```
main.cpp:38:10: warning: libstdc++ version: 20230801 [-W#pragma-messages]
```

Checkout also: https://iq.opengenus.org/find-glibc-version/